# How to automatically adjust rows in export/report sheet based on the data in Excel-VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Basically I have data of multiple individuals, lets call them A, B and C, for which I have transaction information for each, which is updated regularly. For example, A has had 15 transactions since inceptions, B has had 10 and C has had 6.

I have created a sheet that using a drop down list to select A, B or C will use their respective data to produce the report. However, in one section I produce a ledger which list all transactions by date with all relevant info. I have produced this with "hard-coded" ID numbers where I have a pre-defined area of 15 rows which is populated accordingly. I the case of A, no issue. But in the case of B or C, since they have less data, large blank spaces are left (if formula doesn't find data, then N/A turns to blank cell).

In other words I need for example for person A, C10:E25 to be populated, leaving the next section starting at row 27 for example. For person B, C10:E20 with the next section starting at row 22, and similarly, person C, C10:E16 and row 18 respectively.

I have been unable to find a question/answer that will help me do this. Over time, more data  will gather so it needs to be dynamic. I am new to VBA but have used it to create a simple "print to PDF with name REPORTNAME_DATETODAY" button.

Thanks

EDIT:

I have made an excel file using random numbers and dates to illustrate my question.

DATA Sheet

[image: DATA Sheet]

Output Example

[image: Output Example 1]

As you can see, depending on the individual, there are more or less white "blank" spaces which I want removed (I have been doing manually per person so far...).

Note 1:
In the output sheet, the ranges A5:A19 and A23:A37 are made invisible on the final report, I just left them there to make their use clear.

Note 2:
Formulas used in the tables are the following as arrays:
{=IFNA(INDEX(DATA!$B$1:$B$33,MATCH(1,(DATA!$A$1:$A$33=$C$2)*(DATA!$D$1:$D$33=$A$4)*(DATA!$F$1:$F$32=$A5),0))," ")}

Perhaps it isn't the most efficient way, but that's what I have managed so far. I'm open to suggestions!

EDIT 2: Found this code on the internet which seems to work with regards to deleting empty rows (containing " ") with one go. But it doesn't allow me to run the code, print to pdf, then CTRL-Z, change person, repeat. 
My only workaround is to create a copy of the sheet, run the code, print to pdf, delete the sheet. Repeat by copying the main sheet again, change person, code, print.. etc..

Maybe there is a way make it easier...

here's the code i found (courtesy of Ron de Bruin)

```
Sub Thing()
 Dim Firstrow As Long
  Dim Lastrow As Long
  Dim Lrow As Long
  Dim CalcMode As Long
  Dim ViewMode As Long

  With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
  End With

'We use the ActiveSheet but you can replace this with
'Sheets("MySheet")if you want
With ActiveSheet

    'We select the sheet so we can change the window view
    .Select

    'If you are in Page Break Preview Or Page Layout view go
    'back to normal view, we do this for speed
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

    'Turn off Page Breaks, we do this for speed
    .DisplayPageBreaks = False

    'Set the first and last row to loop through
    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

    'We loop from Lastrow to Firstrow (bottom to top)
    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

        'We check the values in the A column in this example
        With .Cells(Lrow, "B")

            If Not IsError(.Value) Then

                If .Value = " " Then .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "ron"
                'in Column A, case sensitive.

            End If

        End With

    Next Lrow

End With

ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With
End Sub
```

EDIT 3: Found a solution.. or workaround by hiding the rows that contain the " " instead of deleting. Created a macro to hide and one to unhide.. so each report's steps are hide, print, unhide...

Comment: won't let me post more than 2 links, so second example isn't there but it's the same with the tables filled in in more places..

Answer (score 0):

Please post what you have tried so far.

Without fully understanding what you achieve, I assume you need two output areas, that are separated by a blank line.

I suggest you look into the `Range.Offset`-property [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx).

You could then shift your output-area based on your starting cell and the number of transactions with something like

```
Dim r as Integer
r = 'go get the number of transactions somewhere

Dim rngOut as Range
Set rngOut = Sheets("Output").Range("C10").Offset(r + 2, 0)
```

Comment: provided an example of what I have so far above.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you write your code...

```
LastRow = Sheets("Sheetname").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

This function is very helpful when using VBA to get the range based on the data. It will return the number of the last cell that contains data on the specified column. In this case it will return the row number of the last cell that contains data on the 1st column (See the 1 argument in cells).